# Having too many specialized exceptions; is this an issue?

Tags: python, exception

Is there a potential problem with having a large amount of different exceptions if they are all derived from some package specific exception? For example, I have `FooException`. From there, I then have `OutOfRangeOfSomethingException`, `RanOutOfBufferException`, `OverflowMapBoundaryException` all from that package specific base `FooException`. I know that having this base allows users and myself to

```
try:
    #stuff
except FooException:
    #Catch all my exceptions, but let default Python ones still raise
```

But are there any other issues with this? Should I try for a few more generalized exceptions, or lots of specific ones?

*N.B. By specific, I'm talking about being able to use in more than one place. I don't plan on having* `IntWasSlightlyTooLargeForInitializationOfMemoryObjectException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more exception types you have, the more exception types you have to maintain.  It's a matter of how fine-grained the control you require over your exceptions is versus how much you want to have to continue maintaining that fine-level grain across the board.  There's no real performance penalty for having a more rich exception hierarchy, the question is whether or not it's truely useful to have something so deep.

Comment: I think it makes testing easier and more stable.
For example, checking for one of the many ``ValueError``s that your code generates requires your tests and user-code to check the strings of these errors. Like any good piece of code, having appropriately named exceptions is way better than having to deal with 20 tests failing because the library developer changed the text in his ValueError exception.

2 cents. Use more specific exceptions.